# Show bash prompt after killing a process in tmux

Tags: bash, tmux

If I run create a tmux session like this:

```
tmux new -d -s dev -n server -c ~/projects 'make run-server'
```

I now have a window running my make task. If I attach to that window and press ctrl+c, because I have `remain-on-exit` enabled, I will see "Pane is dead". `:relaunch-pane` will re-run `make run-server`, but what I really want when I press ctrl+c is to see the Bash prompt, allowing me to enter whatever command I want.

Is there any way to do this besides creating a generic window and typing the command manually each time I create it?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by sending keys in a separate command:

```
tmux new -d -s dev -n server -c ~/projects
tmux send-keys -t dev:server 'make run-server' Enter
```